# Reset Observable timer if an operation called

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am newbie with `Reactive Extensions` but What is the best way to implement below scenario using `Reactive Extensions`:

1- Subscribe an event for every minute in constructor

2- if an operation get called then that subscriber get reset

3- if nothing happened or that operation won't be called for a minute the event in step 1 get fired

Something like this:

```
 public class ImportClient : Carrier<IImportService>, IImportService
{
    IObservable<long> proxyCleaner;
    void DisposeProxy(long interval)
    {
        this.Close();
        //Dispos proxy
    }
    public void RunDisposeTimer()
    {
        proxyCleaner = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        proxyCleaner.Subscribe(DisposeProxy);
    }

    public ImportClient(String endpointConfigurationName) : base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
        RunDisposeTimer();
    }
    public Attach_DTO_OUT AttachImage(AttachImage_DTO_IN source_C)
    {
        //Reset timer here
        //Reset proxyCleaner
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(this.InnerChannel))
        {
            AddMessageHeader<Token>(Token);
            return base.Channel.AttachImage(source_C);
        }
    }
}
```

because my WCF service is Session Full I need to dispose it manually after specific time.

**UPDATE:**

I think it is possible to do with `ObservableCollection` but how:

```
  private ObservableCollection<string> collection;

    public void RunDisposeTimer()
    {
        collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        collection.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged; 
    }
    private void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here reset timer
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```